# Align Bootstrap 4 navbar links to bottom

Tags: bootstrap-4, navbar

```
I want bootstrap 4.1 navbar links to be vertically aligned to bottom of the navbar.  The links are currently aligned centered vertically. I have given height of 150px to navbar and given padding of 100px to the navbar-nav and I am able to get them at the bottom but its look distorts when the navbar collapses. Here is the fiddle :
```

https://jsfiddle.net/ctk60df7/1/

```
Please help me
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. Please read [how to ask](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and edit your question to clarify the issue. Also, make sure you follow the [Bootstrap 4 docs](http://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/components/navbar/) to create a properly structured Navbar.

Comment: Also remember that the *code should be placed in the question itself* instead of linking to an external site that may change over time.

Comment: I tried pasting the code in the question but it doesn't took above two tags. Thats' why I created a jsfiddle. I will do some research before posting the question next time. Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll want to use a media query so that the 150px height is only applied *before* the Navbar collapses into the "mobile" vertical mode. For `navbar-expand-lg`, the Navbar collapses at 992px so that media query would be:

```
@media (min-width:992px) {
  .navbar {
    height: 150px;
  }
}
```

Then use `align-items-end` to align the nav links at the bottom.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-dark bg-dark align-items-end">
    <div class="container">
    </div>
</nav>
```

https://www.codeply.com/go/VyB9zsXLCJ

Comment: Well if the height of navbar brand increases align-items-end doesn't works.

Answer (score 0):

You can use
[Fixed-bottom class](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.1/utilities/position/#fixed-bottom)
as your learning resource.